# Automatic detection of Content-Type matching body file type for a HTTP request in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, web

Using the following controller

```
@PostMapping("/upload", consumes = {"application/zip", "text/csv"})
void upload(@RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType, InputStream inputStream) {
    return service.upload(contentType, inputStream);
}
```

the `inputStream`'s actual content is not checked against the `Content-Type`, meaning it would be possible to have `Content-Type` as `application/zip` and upload a .csv file.

Would there be any way to automatically check this in Spring Boot? Preferably without consuming the inputStream. I believe I've seen this in other Java frameworks.

Comment: The media-type a client issues a request for is the key part that allows a server to process the request accordingly. If the client states it is in representation format A but sends one in B representation, a server, that most likely is unable to process the request for the stated media type, should fail the processing and indicate its problems with the request to the client. Hence, I would not recommend such a payload probing approach

Comment: @RomanVottner Thanks for the input. So your advise is to pass that along to whoever consumes it, and if it was an error/mismatch to propagate that back instead of checking it (early) in the controller layer?